# Ag-grid with NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have an Angular application with several ag-grids in in it. It works with different https servers I tried but unfortunately not in production behind nginx.
I have the following recommended setting in nginx config:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-elem 'self';style-src 'self';base-uri 'self';" always;
```

That essentially breaks ag-rid and the grid is completely distorted without style. For example in this ag-grid code I am getting

```
function createEmptyStyleRule(query) {
  if (mediaQueriesForWebkitCompatibility.has(query)) {
  return;
 }

 try {
   if (!mediaQueryStyleNode) {
  mediaQueryStyleNode = document.createElement('style');
  mediaQueryStyleNode.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
```

In this place I am getting: **Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'"**

Since this setup ( ag-grid and nginx) is very common I assume I am doing something wrong here. I cannot relax the css security policy and obviously cannot change the ag-grid code without huge inconvenience or maintaining it with version updates.
Any insights ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Refused+to+apply+inline+style+because+it+violates -- basic research, just looking for the error message online.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I see in https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/security/
That unsafe-inline is required for ag-grid to work so unfortunately this is an expected behavior.